# Multiple modules and routing in angular 5

Tags: angular

can somebody tell me how correct to set up routing when using multiple modules in my project? I have app.module and courses.module with some components declared in. I want to know how to connect modules and edit properly routing in courses.module, thats share routes: "/courses/list" and "/courses/detail"

app.routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

//import { CoursesRoutingModule } from './components/courses/courses-routing.module';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'courses',
    loadChildren: './components/courses/courses-routing.module#CoursesRoutingModule' 
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

app.component.html

```
<h1>App.component</h1>
<p>
    <button routerLink="/">HOME</button>
    <button routerLink="/courses">KURSY</button>
</p>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

And here's courses component:

courses.routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { CoursesComponent } from './courses.component';
import { CoursesDetailComponent } from './components/courses-detail/courses-detail.component';
import { CoursesListComponent } from './components/courses-list/courses-list.component';

const routes: Routes = [
//  {
//    path: 'courses',
//    loadChildren: '/src/app/components/courses/courses.module'
//  }
//  ,
//  {
//    path: 'courses/list',
//    component: CoursesListComponent,
//    outlet: 'courseslist'
//  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class CoursesRoutingModule { }
```

courses.component.html:

```
<p>
    <button routerLink="/">HOME</button>
    <button routerLink="/courses/list">list</button>
    <button routerLink="/courses/detail">detail</button>
</p>
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

**Edit 08/2019**

Adapted the lazy load module syntax to the newly, strong-typed syntax introduced in angular 8.

**Edit 10/2021:**

This construct is still valid for Angular 12.

**Solution**

Here is how I do it:

**app.module.ts**

```ts
import {ModuleRouting} from './app.routing';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
    ],
    imports: [
        ModuleRouting,
        SubmoduleModule         
    ]
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

**app.routing.ts**

```ts
import {Routes, RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import {ModuleWithProviders} from '@angular/core';

const routes: Routes = [
    {path: 'submodule', loadChildren: () => import('app/submodule/submodule.module').then(m => m.SubmoduleModule)}
];

export const ModuleRouting: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

**submodule.module.ts**

```ts
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import {SubmoduleRouting} from './submodule.routing';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        SubmoduleRouting
    ],
    declarations: [
        //...
    ]
})
export class SubmoduleModule {
}
```

**submodule.routing.ts**

```ts
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';
import {ModuleWithProviders} from '@angular/core';

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: SomeComponent,
    },
    {
        path: 'other',
        component: SomeOtherComponent,
    }
];

export const SubmoduleRouting: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(routes);
```

**You can also generate the module and routing files using [the angular cli](https://angular.io/cli/generate#module) and then adapt them:**
(cd to the directory where the files should be created before every command)

```
ng g m module --routing
ng g m submodule --routing
```

Comment: You may want to add that Submodule should be imported by AppModule in this case

Comment: I'm using app-routing.module.ts created by angular cli, in your solution i see module.routing.ts. I bet you have created it by you own. One is module, next is as encapsulated  logic file. What's the correct way?

Comment: Thanks, I've added it @Eeks33

Comment: Do you mean like in this file https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-tour-of-heroes/blob/master/src/app/app-routing.module.ts @Osmiornicanajszybszykucharz?

Comment: Yes, exacly. Is Treated as moudle. Is This changing anything?

Comment: It's really the same as in my example. In the linked file they are using the `@NgModule` decorater, but both are treated as a Module. You can see in my example, the exported type ist `ModuleWithProviders` which is the interface for Angular Modules. (You can do it the way you have it now)

Comment: `ModuleRouting` is exported twice, once in `app.routing.ts` and once in `submodule.routing.ts`. Is this a typo?

Comment: Hey @AsGoodAsItGets. No it's not a typo. The const `ModuleRouting` is only used within the module itself (in `*.module.ts`), so it can be named the same for every module.

Comment: Ok, but isn't this a bit confusing? Shouldn't they be named differently at least for better readability?

Comment: You could include the modules name if you want `export const SubmoduleRouting: ...`

Comment: This is covered in https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 2):

app.routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    children: [
      { path: 'courses', loadChildren: './components/courses/courses-routing.module#CoursesRoutingModule' }
    ]
  }
];
```

courses.routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    children: [
      { path: 'list', component: CoursesListComponent}
    }
  }
];
```

I would do it this way. Give it a try yourself and see how it goes.

Comment: I got Error: "Component CoursesListComponent is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module." even I have imported this component in courses.module.ts and courses-routing.module.ts.

Comment: have you declared your CoursesListComponent in either courses module or the app module? i.e. add it to the declarations.