# Child routes and Modules

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on a semi-big project and I wanted to split it in modules.
The problem is that i can't access the routes of admin.module.ts.
So in the app.module I have imported the admin Module

```
imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  CommonModule,
  AppRoutingModule,
  FormsModule,
  ReactiveFormsModule,
  HttpModule,
  NgSelectModule,
  AdminModule,
  SharedModule
],
```

my routing module does not have the admin route
in my admin.module.ts. 
The ngModule in admin.module looks like this

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
      AdminComponent,
      AdminLandingComponent
  ], imports: [
      CommonModule,
      AdminRoutingModule
  ]
})
```

and the routes in the admin-routing.module.ts look like this

```
{ path: 'admin', component: AdminComponent, children: [
  { path: '', component: AdminLandingComponent }
]}
```

I use forChild() so that is not the problem
When i try to access localhost:4200/admin i get redirected to page not-found.
Why does it happen? How to fix it?

## full files

1. parent module - [app module](http://pastebin.com/jD900qVA)
2. main routes  - [app-routing module](http://pastebin.com/qX9U09Gw)
3. submodule - [admin module](http://pastebin.com/VBkyUkMm)
4. child routes - [admin-routing module](http://pastebin.com/RTKx6P23)

Comment: Can you add the routes of your app module pls?

Comment: Everything looks good. I assume you are exporting the routes in your `admin-routing.module.ts` using something like `export const AdminRoutingModule = RouterModule.forChild(routes);`?

Comment: try `loadChildren` in app-routing.module.ts
`{ path: 'admin', loadChildren: () => AdminModule },`
(don't forget to import it in this file)

Comment: @MaksymShevchenko it did not work

Comment: One other thing you can try is to add your AdminRoutingModule to the exports key of the AdminModule e.g.

    `@NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AdminComponent,
        AdminLandingComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        CommonModule,
        AdminRoutingModule
      ],
      exports: [
        AdminRoutingModule
      ]
    })`

Comment: @MattMcNabb No, that doesn't fix it

Comment: @TraqnRaykovski after you declared 'admin' path in `app-routing.module.ts` you should change your admin(child routes).
in this case you should only have one route `{ path: '', component: AdminLandingComponent }`

Comment: Just came across this over SO post, let me know if it helps:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47353218/multiple-modules-and-routing-in-angular-5

Comment: @MattMcNabb yes this was exactly the problem I had. Thanks to Maksym Shevchenko's help I've already fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

@MaksymShevchenko Thank you. 
Adding the path :
`{path: 'admin', loadChildren: '../admin/admin.module#AdminModule'}` 
 in app-routing.module.ts and changing the path in the admin-routing.modules.ts to :
`{path: '', component: AdminComponent, children: [
        {path: '', component:AdminLandingComponent}
    ]}` 
did the trick.

## Another way to fix the problem

Because I added the module in the imports array, anular adds the routes after the wildcard route. The other fix is to export the wildcard route to another module and add it after all other modules in the root module. That way we don't have to play with lazy loading.