# Multiple nested modules and routing in Angular

Tags: angular

I have a project structure similar to something like this:

app.module 
–– dashboard.module 
–– overview.module 
–––– profile.module 
–––––– favorites.module

What you see are four levels of feature modules. (Consider them to have also multiple components etc.)

---

**What would be the best way of setting up routing for these modules?**

I would set up a routing module for every module, like this:
app-routing.module, dashboard-routing.module, overview-routing.module (...)

But is that considered as a good practice in Angular? If not, what should one do instead?

Comment: Have you checked this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47353218/multiple-modules-and-routing-in-angular-5/47353436

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each module should have their own routing file so the concerns remain separate.
Its a good practice and i think you should go with this approach.

For Example, an Authentication module should handle its own routing like:
/login, /signup, /forgot-password etc.

Comment: I agree on that so far.

Comment: @L.Heider Thanks :) could you please accept this answer?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should not create multiple modules for a single type of interface. In your case there is a single application and a single module `app.module` is enough for it.

Now the question is that the alternate approach for another modules ?

So you should create Components for Dashboard, Overview, Profile, Favourites and manage routes in single `app-routing.module` file.

One more thing which should keep in mind, if you have multiple user interface like `admin`, `sub-admin`, `user`, etc. then it would be easy to maintain modules for each interface, and can manage their routing separately.

Comment: But what if I like to implement lazy loading?

Comment: Yes in that case you must go with the Module structure.